# Getting error when using value returned by a function as an input for another function

Tags: python-2.7, function, arduino-uno

I am a starter in using python. I am showing a section of the code I was working on. I was trying to communicate python to an arduino using `pyserial` and blinking a LED. I want to use the value returned by the function `send_data` to be used as an input for function `delay_for_goodant`. But when I run the code, I get the error

> global name data not defined.

Any suggestions to get rid of this?

```
def openthedoor(set_accepted_list):
    if(((len(set_accepted_list)) >0) & (set_forbidden_list == set()):
        print"yes,open the gate"
        use_door(1)
    else:
        print"no,close the gate"
        use_door(0)
    set_for_comparison = set(set_accepted_list &  set_list_ant_id)
    list_for_comparison = list(set_for_comparison)
    return set_for_comparison,list_for_comparison    


def establishing_connection():
    print ser.read();
    ser.write('1')

last_action = -1

def use_door(activate):
    global last_action
    if(last_action != activate):
        send_data(activate)
    last_action = activate



def send_data(data):
    if (data ==0):
        print "manga"
        return True
    else:
        print "muringa"
        return False

def delay_for_goodant(data):
    print "thenga"
    global ser
    try:
        if (ser == None):
            ser = serial.Serial("COM1",9600,timeout = 0)
            print "reconnect"
        if send_data(data) is True:
            ser.write('0')
            time.sleep(0)
            incoming_data = ser.readline()
            print "python is telling arduino to keep the LED dim"
        else:
            ser.write('1')
            time.sleep(0.7)
            incoming_data2 = ser.readline()
            print "python is telling the arduino to keep the LED bright"
    except IOError:
        ser = None
```

I call these functions in later parts of the code as. Am i doing a mistake here? What i am trying to do here is `if data ==0, i want to ser.write('1')`.

```
establishing_connection()
set_for_comparison,list_for_comparison = openthedoor(set_accepted_list)
activate = use_door()
data = send_data(activate)
arabica = delay_for_goodant(data)
```

Also the value inside the function `delay_for_goodant` is not printed.

This is what i get, when i run the code:

```
True
muringa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "door_code_final_calib_dig_2.py", line 352, in <module>
    arabica = delay_for_goodant(data)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in the given code. Could you edit in the full traceback of the error?

Comment: @glibdud the error is added

Comment: Wherever the line `arabica = delay_for_goodant(data)` is (line 352 of the file), that's where the problem is. `data` isn't defined there.

Comment: @mudaliyar Why you don't edit your code giving us a minimal body of the script where you use those functions?

Comment: @SolidSnake. I added a minimal body of the code as suggested. Hope this helps.